# Multi-criteria request on short mysql table

Tags: mysql

I have a table "posts_tags" with 2 fields

```
post_id  tag_id
1          10
1          7
1          9
2          3
2          9
2          10
3          9
3          10
```

I would like return only post_id which contains all posts tags

My request looks like this

```
SELECT * FROM posts_tags WHERE tag_id IN (10, 9) GROUP BY post_id;
```

The request return post_id 1, 2 et 3 ;
I would like only return post_id 3

What's the solution?

Comment: and why should it return only 3???

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT   post_id
FROM     posts_tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING   SUM(tag_id= 9)
     AND SUM(tag_id=10)
     AND NOT SUM(tag_id NOT IN (10,9))
```

Answer (score 1):

I am a fan of aggregation with a `having` clause for these types of "set-within-set" problems:

```
select post_id
from post_tags pt
group by post_id
having sum(case when tag_id = 9 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and  -- has "9"
       sum(case when tag_id = 10 then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and -- has "10"
       sum(case when tag_id not in (9, 10) then 1 else 0 end) = 0  -- has nothing else
```

This takes the conditions that you are looking for and turns them into condition in the having clause.  Your conditions are:

- Has at least one 9
- Has at least one 10
- Has nothing else (that is not a 9 or 10)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM posts_tags WHERE tag_id IN (10, 9) and post_id=3;
```

Comment: you said 'I would like only return post_id 3'. What do you want to mean?

Comment: Excact but it was for example, i don't know id in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT post_id
FROM post_tags
GROUP BY post_id
HAVING
  COUNT(
    DISTINCT CASE WHEN tag_id IN (9,10) THEN tag_id END)=2
  AND COUNT(DISTINCT tag_id)=2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  post_id
FROM posts_tags as pt
WHERE tag_id IN(9,10)
    AND tag_id NOT IN(SELECT
            post_id
              FROM posts_tags
              WHERE tag_id NOT IN(9,10))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is of the best request to do !